# PreferenceActivity и стиль

Tags: android, css, настройки

Буду краток. У меня есть активность настроек. Тема приложения `AppCompat.Light`.

Однако когда я запускаю активность настроек, она показывается без `ActionBar`.

В чем проблема? Мне нужно чтобы `ActionBar` отображался.

Файл манифеста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dimantik.myapplication">
    >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".TopActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateTaskActivityFirst"
            android:label="Новая задача"
            android:parentActivityName=".TopActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowTaskActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".TopActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".EditTaskActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".TopActivity"
            android:label="Настройки"/>

        <service
            android:name=".MyIntentService"
            android:exported="false">

        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Код **SettingsActivity**:

```
package com.example.dimantik.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
 * Created by Dimantik on 02.11.2016.
 */

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что `PreferenceActivity` не имеет `ActionBar`.

И вообще, метод `PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(...)` является `deprecated`, следовательно, **его лучше не использовать**.

Если Вам нужен именно `ActionBar`, то предложу решение, основанное на использовании `PreferenceFragment`:

Создаете класс `SettingsFragment`:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

И изменяете Вашу `SettingsActivity`:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

В итоге получаете представление с желаемым `ActionBar`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]